# How do parcelable in Android know which variable to read in its constructor?

Tags: android, parcelable

You can see from the code below, parcel don't read any key for return the value. How do they know what to read and put into variable `someString1` or `someString2` and so on?

```js
public SomeObject(Parcel in) {

   this.someString1 = in.readString();
   this.someString2 = in.readString();
   this.someInt = in.readInt();
   this.someString3 = in.readString();
   this.someInt2 = in.readInt();

}
```

What if I put it this way. Will the following code become error, because I change the order to read it?

```js
public SomeObject(Parcel in) {

this.someString3 = in.readString();
this.someInt2 = in.readInt();
this.someString1 = in.readString();
this.someString2 = in.readString();
this.someInt = in.readInt();

}
```

Comment: http://www.parcelabler.com/ <-- my favorite site for auto-parceling. No muss, no fuss!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changing the order will definitely cause issues. Values are written sequentially, so whatever order you write the fields out to in `writeToParcel()`, you *must* read them back in in the same order when reading from the `Parcel`.